# Failed to install protobuf using pip3

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to install protobuf via pip3 and I'm stuck with an error:

  `Failed building wheel for protobuf
  Running setup.py clean for protobuf
Failed to build protobuf
Installing collected packages: protobuf
  Running setup.py install for protobuf ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\python350\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-3z6exhcv\\protobuf\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CL57586\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mza8nb7f-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    Generating google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py...
    Can't find required file: ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`

python version is 3.5.0
using command like this:
`pip3 install protobuf`

When I clone all the code from https://github.com/google/protobuf.git and try to install from local, I just got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

`pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow`